# Plone 4 EEA Faceted Navigation - How to register a custom view

Tags: plone

I have installed `eea.facetednavigation` and it works fine so far. But I want to register a new result view and don't know how to hook here.

Do I have to use a non-grokked view? Or is there a special interface that could be used for `grok.context` (This is what I've tried so far with `IFacetedNavigable`, but no success)

**Update**

As recommended, I declared my view with `faceted:view` in my `configure.zcml`

It does not work at all. I am on Plone4.3. I'm pretty shure that I declared the view as described in the example, but cannot select it in the dropdown. When I construct a request that tries to set my custom view, I get an `Invalid view id` error.

I can test the view, by appending the view name to a url with a folderish content. It works. Just the registration is not done entirely. I get some kss errors too, when I reinstall the affected addon. There may be a relation.

Update II

After deactivating and activating facetednavigation, the view appeared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in eea.facetednavigation.views there is an example. Basically you'll need to register your view with zcml faceted:view meta directive.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but it is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I customized the eea.facetednavigation view only once, but it was really simple by using [z3c.jbot](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/z3c.jbot) (no need of ZCML or grok in this case).